# Having trouble parsing received data from SignalR

Tags: swift, websocket, signalr

When trying to parse the data received, the values are nil, I can see the received data in the debug log, but just cannot parse the data.

I am using
https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift

```
   self.chatHubConnection!.on(method: "SendMessage", callback: { (payload: ArgumentExtractor?) in
            let response = try! payload?.getArgument(type: SignalR?.self)
            print("Response: \(response!)")
        })
```

Model

```
struct SignalR: Codable {
    let type: Int?
    let target: String?
    let arguments: [Argument]?
}

struct Argument: Codable {
    let id: ID


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
    }
}

struct ID: Codable {
    let timestamp, machine, pid, increment: Int
    let creationTime: Date
}
```

Comment: Make all struct members in `SignalR` non-optional to get errors instead of *nil-silence*. And please consolidate your question and exclamation marks. `try! payload?.` is pretty bad practice. And since you decode a iso8601 string as `Date` have you applied the appropriate date decoding strategy?

Comment: It looks like the issue might be with the payload parameter in the callback function. The ArgumentExtractor type does not conform to the Decodable protocol, so you will not be able to directly decode the payload into a SignalR object using JSONDecoder. One option to parse the data would be to manually extract the relevant fields from the payload object and use them to create a SignalR object. You can do this by using the getString, getInt, and getArray methods of the ArgumentExtractor object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `do try catch` so you can get a better error instead of a crash.

```
self.chatHubConnection!.on(method: "SendMessage", callback: { (payload: ArgumentExtractor?) in
        do{
            let response = try payload?.getArgument(type: SignalR?.self)
            print("Response: \(response!)")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    })
```